# how to drag-and-drop from ScatterView to LibraryBar

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

It is easy to drag-and-drop from LibraryBar to ScatterView.
How can I drag-and-drop from ScatterView to LibraryBar?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed MSDN article about dragging from ScatterView controls to SurfaceListBox controls.  Perhaps this technique will also apply to dropping to a LibraryBar?

[Dragging and Dropping Items from ScatterView Controls to SurfaceListBox Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804829%28Surface.10%29.aspx)